# Spring annotations with JSF

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-annotations

Can anybody tell me how should I use Spring annotations in JSF application so that I can use spring annotations (eg. @Service or @Component) instead of @ManagedBean and use that bean in EL expressions on jsf view page.
First I would like to know whether it is possible or not? And if yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

It's available using the `org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver`.

I wrote up a tutorial for it a while back, have a look at http://papweb.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/spring-mvc-3-jsf-2-with-maven-2-and-tomcat/.